# How to check to see if people are in my network, without logging on to LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I would like to have my Admin review a list of poeple, and tell me who on that list is in my 1st or 2nd degree network.

Can I do this without giving them my logon information?

In other words, can person A check if Person B is in Person C's network if Person C gives Person A permission to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If person A is in person C's network then person A should be able to look up person B and se which degree of separation there is between person A and person B. If person C is between person A and person B then LinkedIn should state it.